# Browser navigation issue in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have started learning selenium WebDriver recently. I was trying to automate a simple task of launching a browser and  logging into an account using Firefox browser.

The difference I noticed is when I opened the browser manually and click on login link from homepage, a small pop-up window is opened to accept login credentials. I captured the elements (i.e username, password and login) using Firebug and completed my script(using Java).

But when I ran the same script, after a click on login link from home page,browser navigated to new page(instead of pop up window on same page which opened during manual process) to accept login credentials (whose web elements(i.e username, password and login)values are completely different than one captured during manual process). Which finally leads to 'NoSuchElementException'.

Any reason why we see the difference while launching browser through selenium? And also how to handle these scenarios in live environment?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sri.

Comment: Read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to follow the guidelines and refine your question to show your efforts such sample code attempted to solve the problem and error message if any.

Comment: @Sri Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle dynamic element .One is as below:
firstly ,differenciate the data which is changing dynamically and accordingly try to find element like
1.for text box
XPath: //input[contains(@class, 'Common Data')]
2.for Button
XPath: //button[starts-with(@id, 'Common Data anything which starts with')] 
It would be more clear if you provide your HTML code. 
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are saying that there are 2 different types of "Login" page and the script you wrote only works for one of them.

So what you need to do now is to write an **if condition** to check which login page type is detected and then perform the authentication accordingly.